# How to close(or in background) other running app when I start my application?

Tags: android

ON call disconnect I am starting my app by MyBroadcastreceiver using PHONE_STATE. For that I have added PHONE_STATE in my receiver in manifest file. My application is working fine. There are some application which are working on same concept e.g application runs on Call disconnect.
Currently when those apps are installed on my device(for exp TrueCaller) then on call disconnect my app is running in background and said app is in foreground. How to run my application in foreground instead of truecaller at call disconnect.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am  afraid that android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE broadcast can not been aborted by app.

So the other app can receive this and response it just like you do.